Issue with updating cart total in flutter/dart app
I'm making a cart page for my e-commerce app, when I try to print out the total of the items in the cart on the debug console it prints out the expected result even after increasing/decreasing the quantity of items,  but in the UI  the total amount doesnt update accordingly when i click on the decrease/increase quantity button. E.g let's say the total of my item is $2222, the total will display that number but when increase the quantity of the item to 2 nothing happens even though the quantity of the item has changed, then when i click it after that the total amount updates this time but then the calculation will be wrong because it didnt calculate the total when the quantity of the item was at 2.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:watch_hub/models/cart.dart';
import 'package:watch_hub/services/database.dart';

class GetPrice {
//I USE THIS STATIC VARIABLE TO ASSIGN THE TOTAL TO IT AND DISPLAY IN THE CART PAGE
  static num price = 0;
}

class CartList extends StatefulWidget {
  const CartList({super.key});

  @override
  State<CartList> createState() => _CartListState();
}

class _CartListState extends State<CartList> {
  int? counter;
  static int? price;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cart = Provider.of<List<Cart>>(context);
    double maxWidth = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;

    List totalPriceList = [];
  
    // cart.sort();

    cart.forEach((cart) {
      print("cart model is ${cart.brand}");
    });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Cart"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: cart.length,
        itemBuilder: (
          context,
          index,
        ) {
          int? price;
          int? initialQuantity = cart[index].quantity;
          GetPrice.quantity = cart[index].quantity;
          totalPriceList.add(cart[index].price! * cart[index].quantity!);

          totalPriceList.reduce((value, element) {
            GetPrice.price = element + value;
          });

       //WHEN I PRINT THIS I GET THE EXPECTED RESULT EVEN AFTER CHANGING QUANTITIES IT OUTPUTS THE CORRECT RESULT EVERYTIME
          print("total is ${GetPrice.price.toString()}");

          return Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                // height: 50,
                child: ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        cart[index].image!,
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      cart[index].model!,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      cart[index].brand!,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    trailing: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        IconButton.filled(
                          style:
                              IconButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              cart[index].quantity = cart[index].quantity! - 1;
                            });
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              cart[index].price.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "QTY: ${cart[index].quantity.toString()}",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        IconButton.filled(
                          style: IconButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.green),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              cart[index].quantity = cart[index].quantity! + 1;
                           
                            });
                            // print("total is $price");
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
      bottomSheet: Container(
        height: 130,
        color: Colors.brown[400],
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Total ",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                //THIS IS WHERE I DISPLAY THE TOTAL IN THE CART PAGE
                  child: Text(
                    "\$${GetPrice.price.toString()}",
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 200,
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("Make Order"),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


The main issue is this line
final cart = Provider.of<List<Cart>>(context);
It is inside the build function so it will reset to whatever the  Provider is sending to this widget. When you tap on the green or red buttons, it will trigger a re-build of the widget, which will reset to original cart info.
So the best way to fix this is to use the Provider and Consumer design pattern. For example, this example if very similar to yours. It even sets up a cart! https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifier
But note that you need to use ChangeNotifier and Consumer.
Your consumer will be CartList and your ChangeNotifier is whichever class is sending a list of carts.
Using Provider.of<List<Cart>>(context) makes sense if you are only displaying the data, but you are also changing the data so your ChangeNotifier needs to be told to change the data too.
I encourage you to follow the example and post another question if you get stuck.

I get my cart data from the provider using StreamProvider.value in the parent widget of my CartList widget, do I change that to changeNotifierProvider?

@AbdullahiAbbas it's hard to tell without seeing the code, but you can change whoever is providing the list of carts to be a change notifier, or create a new change notifier that also listens to the whoever is supplying the list of carts.

i made a new question with the updated code after adding the changeNotifierProvider here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78880625/flutter-button-needs-to-be-pressed-twice-for-value-to-change?noredirect=1#comment139075156_78880625
